# Is it possable to iterate all files in a directory and have assign a number to each file and wait for input in cmd script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, winpe

I am attempting to automate a process using a batch script. I want to iterate all the files in a specific directory with a specific file extension (.gho) and do something with it.

I know I can get the file names with "dir /B *.gho" but I would like cmd to list each file name with a number and wait for input then pass file the name off to a variable so it can be combined with another variable containing a command to execute.

Example:

1. WinXP.gho
2. Win7.gho
3. Win10.gho

What image would you like to use?

> 

I know I can write something like this in VB.net but this is going to be used in a PE boot disk and from what I understand .net apps don't work in a PE without some work.
Can someone point me in the right direction, once I know it can be done and what to look for I probably can figure out the rest myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Natsuru. A `FOR` loop can be used to list the file names. Use `CHOICE /?` and read about choosing an option. If you have any problems with the code you have written, copy and paste it into the question as text. Questions without code should go to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `findstr.exe` resides in `%SystemRoot%\System32` of your PE base OS, and the current working directory under which this script is running, holds your target `.gho` files, here's an example template you can use:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "ext=.gho"
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set #) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "*%ext%" 2^> NUL ^| ^
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /N "%ext%"'
) Do Set "#%%G=%%H" & Echo( %%G.    %%H
If Not Defined #1 (Echo No file matches, press a key to exit.
    Pause 1> NUL & GoTo :EOF)
:Opt
Set "opt="
Echo(
Set /P "opt=Enter the number for your chosen file>"
Set "opt=%opt:"=%"
Set # | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L "#%opt%=" 1> NUL || GoTo Opt
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("!#%opt%!") Do EndLocal & Set "opt=%%G"
Echo(
Echo( You Selected %opt%
Pause
```

As this is a template the extension on line 3 is replaceable with any other, as needed. Your own code would be written from line 18, (replacing the three example lines I included just to show you the result, now assigned to `%opt%`. Nothing else between those two lines should be modified.

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can integrate this into my PE with the necessary changes. I'll let you know how it worked out. Never expected all this.

Comment: BTW, I just thought I'd mention, due to site formatting, that the whitespace between `%%G.` and `%%H` on line `7` is a horizontal tab character, not a series of space characters.

Comment: Thank you again, you just gave me a good starting port. I can say my work load will probably be halved. :D